# Four squares, all of different areas, are cut from a rectangle, leaving a smaller rectangle...

Tags: geometry, inequality, self-learning, rectangles

Four squares, all of different areas, are cut from a rectangle, leaving a smaller rectangle of dimensions $1\times2$. If the largest square has area 64, and the other three squares have side lengths that are whole numbers no larger than 7, what are their areas?

*Attempt*

Possible areas are 1,4,9,16,25,36 and 49.

Found this 2,3,5,8 as the answer (@pic). But I want to know that if there exist any other solutions or not. If not, what's the reason?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to draw a picture?

Comment: Could you provide a picture?

Comment: Yes. Tried but I got stuck when i thought that if we try to cut squares then it will always depend on the side length of original triangle for the remaining 3 areas.

Comment: Hint: Start with the 2x1 piece and keep adding squares to it. You wanr to keep it a rectangular shape as you do this, because with so few square pieces you cannot afford creating irregular shapes and hope to make that back into a nice rectangle

Comment: Another hint: Fibonacci.

Comment: @saulspatz I don't know whether I am correct or not. But, I got one arrangement as 13*8 rectangle so that remaining squares will be of side length 2,3 and 5. But, still not able to draw anything significant. I carrying out on the basis of hit and trial.

Comment: @ Dr. Mathva  i have posted a picture of my drawing. @saulspatz

Comment: You are correct in that this is a solution.  Note that the sides of the squares you have used, $2,3,5,8$ are Fibonacci numbers as David K suggested.  What is the problem now?  Are you trying to prove that this solution is the only one, or just looking for confirmation?

Comment: I am looking for any other arrangements or as this solution as only one. @saulspatz

Comment: If you have the $1\times2$ rectangle in the corners, as pictured, the larges square you can put on top of it is $3\times3.$  Otherwise, you have a rectangular area of height $!$ that you couldn't cover with squares of different sizes.  If you place the $3\times3$ square, then you have to place a $1\times1$ square to fill the hole.  No matter how you place the $8\times8$ square, there's no way to complete a rectangle with only one more square.  Now what if the $1\times2$ is placed along an edge, of if it's completely surrounded by squares?

Comment: If 1×2 rect. is placed along an edge then I think it will be adjusted as the neighbour of (1) 3×3 as corner one (2) 2×2 above it. Totally making 1×2; 2×2 & 3×3 as rectangle of area 15 square units. Am I right? @saulspatz

Comment: @jayant98, you would do well to make it clear, in your question, that you have found *one* solution, but would like to find *all* solutions.

Comment: Okay @BarryCipra going to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless one side of the big rectangle is $8$, the $8\times 8$ must touch smaller parts on two edges, which already accounts for all parts. So one of the edges must touch two smaller squares - which leaves a gap at the smaller square that cannot be filled. We conclude that one side of the rectangle is $8$.
After removing the $8\times 8$, we are left with three smaller squares of side-lengths $a<b<c<8$ and the $2\times 1$, forming a rectangle. Again, if the large $c\times c$ square has neighbours on two edges, we run into problems. We conclude that one edge of the rectangle is $c$. Hence we have
$$2+a^2+b^2+c^2=8c. $$
Numerically, we could have $c=7$, then $a^2+b^2=5$, i.e., $a=1$, $b=2$. Or $c=6$, then $a^2+b^2=10$, so $a=1$, $b=3$. Or $c=5$, then $a^2+b^2=13$, so $a=2$, $b=3$. $c=4$ is not possible, nor is $c\le 3$.
One readily sees that it is impossible to fill a $1\times 7$ when one part os $2\times 2$, or fill a $2\times 6$, when one part is $3\times 3$. The remaining case $c=5$ leads to the well-known solution.